# Not able to apply regular expression validator in form using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Validation.js

```
 function Validation() {
var firstname = document.form.firstname;
var middlename = document.form.middlename;
var lastname = document.form.lastname;
var username = document.form.username;
var password = document.form.password;
var pass1 = document.form.pass1;
var bloodgroup = document.form.bloodgroup;
var weight = document.form.weight;
var contact = document.form.contact;
var email = document.form.email;
var address = document.form.address;
var area = document.form.area;
var city = document.form.city;
var donateblood = document.form.donateblood;
if(fname(firstname))
{
    if(mname(middlename))
    {
        if(lname(lastname))
        {
            if(uname(username,5,10))
            {
                if(pass(password))
                {
                    if(cpass(pass1))
                    {
                        if(bg(bloodgroup))
                        {
                            if(weight(weight,50))
                            {
                                if(contact(contact))
                                {
                                    if(email(email))
                                    {
                                        if(address(address))
                                        {
                                            if(area(area))
                                            {
                                                if(city(city))
                                                {
                                                    if(db(donateblood))
                                                    {

                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
else
{
    return false;
}
}

function fname(firstname)
{   
var letters = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;  
if(firstname.value == "" && firstname.value == letters)  
{  
    return true;  
}  
else  
{  
    alert('Firstname must have alphabet characters only');  
    firstname.focus();  
    return false;  
}  
}

function mname(middlename)
{
var letters = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;  
if(middlename.value.match(letters) && middlename.value.length != 0)  
{  
    return true;  
}  
else  
{  
    alert('Middlename must have alphabet characters only');  
    middlename.focus();  
    return false;  
}  
}

function lname(lastname)
{
var letters = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;  
if(lastname.value.match(letters) && lastname.value.length != 0)  
{  
    return true;  
}  
else  
{  
    alert('Lastname must have alphabet characters only');  
    lastname.focus();  
    return false;  
}  
}

function uname(username,mx,my)  
{  
var uname_len = username.value.length;  
if (uname_len == 0 || uname_len >= my || uname_len < mx)  
{  
    alert("Username should not be empty / length should be between "+mx+" to 
"+my);  
    username.focus();  
    return false;  
}  
return true;  
}

function pass(password)
{
var decimal=  /^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[^a-zA-Z0-9])(?!.*\s).
{8,15}$/;
if(inputtxt.value.match(decimal)) 
{
    return true;
}
else
{ 
    alert("Password must have one uppercase letter,one digit and one special 
character...");
    return false;
}
}

function cpass(pass1)
{
if(password.value == pass1.value)
{
    return true;
}
else
{
    alert("Password does not match");  
    pass1.focus();
    return false;
}

}

function bg(bloodgroup) 
{  
    if(bloodgroup.value == "Select Blood Group")  
    {  
    alert("Select your Blood Group from the list");  
    bloodgroup.focus();  
    return false;  
    }  
    else  
    {  
    return true;  
    }  
}

function weight(weight,mx) {
var numbers = /^[0-9]+$/; 
var weight_kg = weight.value;
if(weight.value.match(numbers))  
{
    if(weight_kg > mx)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        alert("Weight must be greater than 50 kg");
        return false;
    }
return true;  
}  
else  
{  
    alert("Weight must have numeric characters only");  
    weight.focus();  
    return false;
}
}

function contact(contact) {
var phoneno = /^\d{10}$/;  
if(contact.value.match(phoneno))  
        {  
            return true;  
        }  
  else  
        {  
        alert("message");  
        return false;  
        }  
}

function email(email) {
var mailformat = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/;  
if(email.value.match(mailformat))  
{  
return true;  
}  
else  
{  
alert("You have entered an invalid email address!");  
email.focus();  
return false;  
}  
}

function address(address) {
var letters = /^[0-9a-zA-Z]+$/;  
if(address.value.match(letters))  
{  
return true;  
}  
else  
{  
alert('Address must have alphanumeric characters only');  
address.focus();  
return false;  
}  
}

function area(area) {
var letters = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;  
if(area.value.match(letters))  
{  
    return true;  
}  
else  
{  
    alert('Area must have alphabet characters only');  
    middlename.focus();  
    return false;  
}  
}

function city(city) {
var letters = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;  
if(area.value.match(letters))  
{  
    return true;  
}  
else  
{  
    alert('City must have alphabet characters only');  
    middlename.focus();  
    return false;  
}  
}

function db(donateblood) {
if(donateblood.value == "How often you have donated blood?")  
{  
alert("Select how often you donate blood from the list");  
donateblood.focus();  
return false;  
}  
else  
{  
return true;  
}  
}
```

Register.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
        <title>Register</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" 
/>
            <script type="application/x-javascript">
            addEventListener("load", function() { 
                setTimeout(hideURLbar, 0); 
            }, false);

            function hideURLbar(){ 
                window.scrollTo(0,1); 
            } 
        </script>
<!-- Custom Theme files -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="all">
    <link href="css/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="all"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/swipebox.css">     
    <link href="css/animate.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all"> <!-- animation -->
    <link href="css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"> <!-- font-awesome icons -->
<!-- //Custom Theme files --> 

<!-- js -->
    <script src="js/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script> 
    <script src="/js/Validation.js"></script>
<!-- //js -->

<!-- web-fonts -->
    <link href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Enriqueta:400,700" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,300italic,400italic,600,600italic,700,700italic,800,800italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<!-- //web-fonts --> 
    <style type="text/css">
        #b1 { color: #999 }
        #header { color: red}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- banner -->
    <div  id="home" class="banner">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="wthree-header">
                <div class="agileits-logo navbar-left">
                    <h1 class="wow swing animated" data-wow-delay=".5s"></h1>
                </div>
                <div class="navbar-right social-icons wow fadeInRight animated" data-wow-delay=".5s"> 
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#" class="fa fa-facebook icon-border facebook"> </a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" class="fa fa-twitter icon-border twitter"> </a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" class="fa fa-google-plus icon-border googleplus"> </a></li> 
                        <li><a href="#" class="fa fa-rss icon-border rss"> </a></li>
                    </ul>  
                </div>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
            </div>
        <!-- navigation -->
        <div class="top-w3lnav">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
                <div class="navbar-header w3l-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">Men</button>
                </div>
            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-center w3l-effect">
                    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="index.html">About Us</a></li> 
                    <li><a href="index.html">Services</a></li> 
                    <li><a href="#team" class="scroll">Guidelines</a></li>
                    <li><a href="index.html">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
            </div>  
            </nav>      
        </div>  
        <!-- navigation --> 
        </div> 
    </div>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <!-- //banner -->
    <!-- welcome -->
    <div class="contact" id="contact"> 
        <div class="container">
            <div class="contact-form">
                <div class="col-md-7 contact-right wow fadeInRight animated" data-wow-delay=".5s">
                    <h5>Login:</h5>
                    <br>
                    <form action="http://localhost:8081/BloodBank/BB/Database" method="get" name= "form" onsubmit="return Validation(); ">
                        <table class="table" width="100">
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    First Name:
                                </td>
                                <td width="500px">
                                    <input type="text" name="firstname">
                                </td>
                            </tr>           
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    Middle Name:
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="text" name="middlename">
                                </td>
                            </tr>   
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    Last Name:
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="text" name="lastname">
                                </td>
                            </tr>  
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    Username:
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="text" name="username">
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    Password:
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="password" name="password">
                                </td>
                            </tr>   
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    Confirm Password:
                                </td>
                                <td width ="50">
                                    <input type="password" name="pass1">
                                </td>
                            </tr>   
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    Date Of Birth:
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="date" name="dob">
                                </td>   
                            </tr>     
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    Gender:
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Male" checked="checked">Male
                                    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Female">Female
                                </td>
                            </tr>  
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    Blood Group:
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <select name="bloodgroup">
                                        <option value="Select Blood Group" selected="">
                                            Select Blood Group
                                        </option>
                                        <option value="A+">
                                            A+
                                        </option>
                                        <option value="B+">
                                            B+
                                        </option>
                                        <option value="O+">
                                            O+
                                        </option>
                                        <option value="AB+">
                                            AB+
                                        </option>
                                        <option value="AB-">
                                            AB-
                                        </option>
                                        <option value="A-">
                                            A-
                                        </option>
                                        <option value="B-">
                                            B-
                                        </option>
                                        <option value="O-">
                                            O-
                                        </option>
                                    </select>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    Weight:
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="text"  name="weight">
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    Contact:
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="text" name="contact">
                                </td>           
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    Email:
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="text" name="email">
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    Date Of Last<br>
                                    Blood Donation:
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="date"  name="lastdate">
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    Address:
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="text" name="address">
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    Area:
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="text" name="area">
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    City:
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="text" name="city">
                                </td>
                            </tr>  
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    How Often you have donated<br>blood in past?
                                </td>   
                                <td>
                                    <select name="donateblood">
                                        <option value="How often you have donated blood?" selected="">
                                            How often you have donated blood?
                                        </option>
                                        <option value="Yet to Donate">
                                            Yet to Donate
                                        </option>
                                        <option value="Regular Donor">
                                            Regular Donor
                                        </option>
                                        <option value="On need of basis">
                                            On need of basis
                                        </option>
                                    </select>
                                </td>
                            </tr>   
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <input class="wow zoomIn animated" data-wow-delay=".5s" type="submit" name="submit" value="SUBMIT" >
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <input class="wow zoomIn animated" data-wow-delay=".5s" type="reset" name="Reset" value="RESET">
                                </td>
                            </tr>            
                        </table>  
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- contact -->    
        <div class="contact" id="contact"> 
            <div class="container">
                <h3 class="w3layouts-title wow fadeInDown animated" data-wow-delay=".5s">Contact Us</h3> 
                <div class="contact-form">
                    <div class="col-md-7 contact-right wow fadeInRight animated" data-wow-delay=".5s">
                        <h5>Feedback Us:</h5>
                        <br>
                        <form action="#" method="post">  
                            <input type="text" name="Name" placeholder="Name" required="">
                            <input type="text" class="email" name="Email" placeholder="Email" required="">
                            <input type="text" name="Phone no" placeholder="Phone" required="">
                            <textarea name="Message" placeholder="Message" required=""></textarea>
                            <input class="wow zoomIn animated" data-wow-delay=".5s" type="submit" value="SUBMIT" > 
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-5 contact-left">
                        <div class="address address-mdl wow fadeInLeft animated" data-wow-delay=".5s">
                            <h5>Phones:</h5>
                            <p>
                                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone"></i> 
                                +9900887766
                            </p>
                            <p>
                                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-phone"></i> 
                                +11 222 333
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="address wow fadeInLeft animated" data-wow-delay=".5s">
                            <h5>Email:</h5>
                            <p>
                                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></i>
                                    <a href="mailto:info@example.com">
                                        mail@example.com
                                    </a>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <!-- //contact -->
    <!-- footer -->
        <div class="footer">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <!-- //footer -->
    <!-- copy right -->
        <div class="footer-bottom">
            <div class="container"></div>
        </div>  
    <!-- //copy right -->   
    <!-- animation --> 
        <script src="js/wow.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            new WOW().init();
        </script>
    <!-- //animation --> 
    <!-- start-smooth-scrolling -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/move-top.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/easing.js"></script> 
        <script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
                $(".scroll").click(function(event){     
                    event.preventDefault();
                    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:$(this.hash).offset().top},1000);
                });
            });
        </script>
    <!-- //end-smooth-scrolling -->
    <!-- smooth-scrolling-of-move-up -->
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
            $().UItoTop({ easingType: 'easeOutQuart' });
        });
        </script> 
    <!-- //smooth-scrolling-of-move-up -->
    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
</body>
```

Whenever I click on submit button,it is automatically redirected to another page...alert message is not shown.

i.e. it does not call the Validation.js page.

Error dialog box is shown for empty field but it is not displayed if i apply regular expression validator

Comment: you may create a fiddle or make the code executable here, so we can refactor whats happening.

Comment: The way to apply a regular expression validation in JS, first you must create a `RegExp` object, passing your expression string as parameter, and then do a `test()` passing your string you want to match to your exp as a parameter

Comment: um, the html does not reference "validation.js" anywhere that I can see.

Comment: in the HTML it's called Validate.js, you list your js file as Validation.js.  typo?

Comment: @lixus i have tried as you said,but then also it doesn't worked

Answer (score 0):

You need to prevent the default postback action before you can run the Javascript.

The following should work:

```
<form action="http://localhost:8081/BloodBank/BB/Database" method="get" name= "form" onsubmit="event.preventDefault(); Validation(); ">
```

Comment: I tried this code,now when i clicked on submit button,no event is performed,It is not redirecting nor it is applying javascript